# get current user phone number using javascript sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript

How do i get current logged in user phone number.
I have a list with field name Requestor, Department and Phone Numver and using below code:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/sputility.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {  
    // get the title of current user  
    var UserName= $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({  
    fieldName: "Title",  
   debug: false  
});  
// get department of current user
var userDepartment = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
   fieldName: "Department"
   });
     // alert(userDepartment);

// get Phone of current user
var userPhone = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
   fieldName: "Phone Number"
   });
      alert(userPhone);


//alert("Hi");
//populate the field ‘Requestor’ with the current account  
$('textarea[title="Requestor"]').val(UserName);  
$('input[title="Requestor"]').val(UserName);  

$('textarea[title="Department"]').val(userDepartment); 
$('input[title="Department"]').val(userDepartment); 


$('textarea[title="Phone Number"]').val(userPhone); 
$('input[title="Phone Number"]').val(userPhone);

});  

</script>
```

I am getting user name and department name but could not get phone number.
Is there anything wrong in naming convention. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [documentation for SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation)

The name of the field you want is Work Phone, not Phone Number.

As a side point, you should not be making three calls to SPServices to get the three field values. You can get all three values in a single call. The documentation has an example showing how to do this.

Comment: I have added:
var userPhone = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "WorkPhone"
});

$('textarea[title="WorkPhone"]').val(userPhone); 
$('input[title="WorkPhone"]').val(userPhone);
but this is again not working, list field name is WorkPhone as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WorkPhone` instead of `Phone Number`.

Also check user profile properties and make sure its is mapped to the correct field.

```
var userPhone = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "WorkPhone"
});
```

Comment: I have added:
var userPhone = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "WorkPhone"
});

$('textarea[title="WorkPhone"]').val(userPhone); 
$('input[title="WorkPhone"]').val(userPhone);
but this is again not working, list field name is WorkPhone as well